# how to add a new line into mongodb using mongoose express and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an app that was built using authentication method suggested in this great tutorial:
http://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

It is using mongoose, mongodb and express its working great!

I have now tried to integrate Stripe payments with it. I am trying to create a new Paymentcard model the same way the tutorial created the user model and add the card when there is a success creation of a new customer.

This is my model:

```
// app/models/paymentcard.js
// load the things we need
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// define the schema for our user model
var paymentcardSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    card           : {
        stripe_customer_id: String,
        user_id: String,
        id: String,
        last4: String,
        brand: String,
        funding: String,
        exp_month: String,
        exp_year: String,
        fingerprint: String,
        country: String
    }

});


// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('Paymentcard', paymentcardSchema);
```

I am then trying to add a new payment card using the following inside the routes.js file:

```
stripe.customers.listCards(id, function(err, cards) {
  // asynchronously called
var newpaymentcard           = new Paymentcard();

newpaymentcard.save(function(err) {
    if (err)
        throw err;

    return 'done';
});





});
```

However in the log I get this error when that bit of code is executed:

```
/Users/adamcooke/Dropbox/node/authenticateexample/app/routes.js:259
                    var newpaymentcard           = new Paymentcard();
                                                       ^
ReferenceError: Paymentcard is not defined
    at /Users/adamcooke/Dropbox/node/authenticateexample/app/routes.js:259:56
    at null._onTimeout (/Users/adamcooke/Dropbox/node/authenticateexample/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:78:34)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)

npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.10.34
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.16
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! nodetest2@0.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
```

Any ideas what I am missing? I think it is something to do with the way i have defined the paymentcard model or that I am not making it available somehow in the routes.js.

I have the code on github also if you need a better look:

https://github.com/cookiejest/authenticationexample

Comment: I don't see where you're using `require` to pull in the `Paymentcard` model. Where's that done?

Comment: my understanding is that is done in the passport.js file in the config folder

Comment: That `Paymentcard` var is private to the passport.js file (and not used as far as I can tell); you'd need to add the same thing to routes.js.

Comment: hmm that was it! Thanks! Is it acceptable to put this much stuff in routes.js or does it not really matter?

Comment: It's usually better to put your route handing functions in separate modules that then pull in just the models they need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Paymentcard` var in passport.js is private to that file (and not used as far as I can tell). You need to add the same line to routes.js so that it's also available in that file.

```
var Paymentcard = require('../app/models/paymentcard');
```